# Xamarin.Forms: Process URI Arguments When App is Called From Another App

Tags: xamarin.forms

Xamarin Form's Device.OpenURI allows you to call an App and pass some arguments embedded within the URI. In turn, I am wondering whether there is a way for the called App to process this URI? I would prefer handling this processing only within the shared code. Any ideas?

Comment: I guess you are not talking about consuming RESTful services, but about two-way inter-app communication, like f.x. a chat service like Skype or Viber or Bluetooth communcation or something like that?

Comment: More like the equivalent of starting an Windows executable with arguments. So both Apps could reside on the same device. I just would like to pass some operational parameters to the callee and figured that OpenURI is my best bet.

Comment: I guess they would both have to be active on the device and one of them would be serving as a kind of server, unless you want to run with a webserver as a middleman with both Apps as "listening" polling clients. I guess you could be using HttpRequest with a service to poll for data, perhaps using JSON and run some tasks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to register a URI scheme for my app (https://xamarinhelp.com/uri-scheme/)